# Get column values for containing a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv that looks like the below. I was wondering what the best way would be to keep the first few cols (id, account_id, date, amount, payments) intact while creating a new column containing the column name for observations with an 'X' marked.

The first 10 rows of the csv look like:

```
id,account_id,date,amount,payments,24_A,12_B,12_A,60_D,48_C,36_D,36_C,12_C,48_A,24_C,60_C,24_B,48_D,24_D,48_B,36_A,36_B,60_B,12_D,60_A
4959,2,1994-01-05,80952,3373,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4961,19,1996-04-29,30276,2523,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4962,25,1997-12-08,30276,2523,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4967,37,1998-10-14,318480,5308,-,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4968,38,1998-04-19,110736,2307,-,-,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4973,67,1996-05-02,165960,6915,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4986,97,1997-08-10,102876,8573,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4988,103,1997-12-06,265320,7370,-,-,-,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4989,105,1998-12-05,352704,7348,-,-,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
4990,110,1997-09-08,162576,4516,-,-,-,-,-,-,X,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-,-
```

[image: Image of dataset]

Comment: Please provide your data as text, not an image.

Comment: @richardec Sorry about that, I've provided the first 10 rows of my dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be something called `lookup` but that's been deprecated in favor of `melt` + `loc[]`.

The idea is to use the `id_vars` as the grouping, and all the other columns get smashed into a single column with their respective value.  Then filter where that value is X, effectively dropping the other rows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.txt')

df = df.melt(id_vars=['id','account_id','date','amount','payments'], var_name='x_col')
df = df.loc[df['value']=='X'].drop(columns='value')

print(df)
```

Output

```
      id  account_id        date  amount  payments x_col
0   4959           2  1994-01-05   80952      3373  24_A
5   4973          67  1996-05-02  165960      6915  24_A
11  4961          19  1996-04-29   30276      2523  12_B
22  4962          25  1997-12-08   30276      2523  12_A
26  4986          97  1997-08-10  102876      8573  12_A
33  4967          37  1998-10-14  318480      5308  60_D
44  4968          38  1998-04-19  110736      2307  48_C
48  4989         105  1998-12-05  352704      7348  48_C
57  4988         103  1997-12-06  265320      7370  36_D
69  4990         110  1997-09-08  162576      4516  36_C
```

Comment: [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) was essentially `melt` + `.loc[]`